# Why php can access 127.0.0.1 but can not access localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I am sure that my hosts file doesn't have any problem. And the outputs of `ping localhost` and `ping 127.0.0.1` are the same. So where may the problem arise?

Here is what mysql shows when I executed `show grants`

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What are you doing? Whats the error message that you get? Can you provide more information ?

Comment: @Federkun When I tried to connect to mysql using localhost, it shows `Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. And it succeed when I use 127.0.0.1

Comment: Login with 127.0.0.1 and check with "SHOW GRANTS" your privilege.

Comment: @Federkun I have added the output to my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/544187/cant-connect-to-mysql-using-localhost-but-using-127-0-0-1-its-ok. Keep in mind that MySQL separates between access via IP address (127.0.0.1) and the special host "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure you have a user for every specific host you want to connect from. You can use wildcards in the address like `'root'@'192.168.1.%'` or `'root'@'%'` to allow access from anywhere but that would make security gurus cringe.